# Removing frame while keeping axes in pyplot subplots

Tags: matplotlib, frame, axes, subplot

I am creating a figure with 3 subplots, and was wondering if there is any way of removing the frame around them, while keeping the axes in place?

Answer (score 39):

If you want to remove the axis spines, but not the other information (ticks, labels, etc.), you can do that like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7,1, sharex=True)

t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

for i, a in enumerate(ax):
    a.plot(t, np.sin((i + 1) * 2 * np.pi * t))
    a.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    a.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    a.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
```

or, more easily, using [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7,1, sharex=True)

t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

for i, a in enumerate(ax):
    a.plot(t, np.sin((i + 1) * 2 * np.pi * t))

seaborn.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True)
```

Both approaches will give you:

[image]

Comment: If you happen to have polar plots, spines are defined differently, so per http://stackoverflow.com/a/22848030/1034716 you need to do: a.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)

Comment: In Python 3, the for loop is even simpler: ```for a in ax:```

Comment: @mwaskom How would I keep the x-axis at the last subplot in the above code?

Answer (score 39):

Try `plt.box(on=None)` It removed *only* the bounding box (frame) around plot, which is what I was trying to do.

`plt.axis('off')` removed tick labels and the bounding box, which wasn't what I was looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve something like this with the `axis('off')` method of an axis handle. Is this the kind of thing you are after? (example code below the figure).

[image: subplots without axes shown]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7,1)

t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

for i, a in enumerate(ax):
    a.plot(t, np.sin((i+1)*2*np.pi*t))
    a.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ax.set_frame_on(False)
```

It removes the box frame around any plot, but the x and y ticks remain.