# how to remove all indicators from pyplot.polar

Tags: matplotlib

i need to make a polar plot with just the main data content visible.
for now i have managed to get the following image by using these simple codes.
but there is still one outline circle left around it. how can i remove it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1800,2200,(24*60))
data = list(data)
data.append(data[0])
print(data)
theta = np.arange(0,360+360/(24*60),360/(24*60))*np.pi/180
plt.polar(theta, data)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig("p.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:
`plt.box(on=None`)

Solution inspired from the Q: [Removing frame while keeping axes in pyplot subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016965/removing-frame-while-keeping-axes-in-pyplot-subplots)